# How to sum of particular column with month and year with fiscal year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, sql-server-2008, pivot

I have following data in my table :

```
uniqueId    d_date      amount
1         2018-02-01    100.25
2         2019-03-01    456.5
3         2018-02-01    455
4         2019-05-01    200.48
5         2018-06-01    100
6         2019-07-01    200
7         2018-12-01    6950
```

Now i want output with fiscal year calculation : (My fiscal year is April-March)

```
Year    Apr    May        Jun  July  Aug   Sept Oct   Nov   Dec  Jan   Feb     Mar    Total
2017     -      -          -    -     -     -    -     -     -    -   552.25    -     552.25
2018     -      -         100   -     -     -    -     -    6950  -    -       456.5  7506.5
2019     -    200.48      -     200   -     -    -     -     -    -    -        -     400.48
```

I can not use PIVOT as it is not supported in my compact sql version.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite similar to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61096631/how-to-sum-of-particular-column-with-month-and-year-wise). Here, you can offset the date by 3 months to compute the fiscal year it belongs to, then do conditional aggregation:

```
select
    year(dateadd(month, -3, d_date)) yr,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = 4  then amount end) Apr,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = 5  then amount end) May,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = 7  then amount end) Jun,
    ...
    sum(case when month(d_date) = 12 then amount end) Dec,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = 1  then amount end) Jan,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = 2  then amount end) Feb,
    sum(case when month(d_date) = 3  then amount end) Mar,
    sum(amount) total
from mytable
group by year(dateadd(month, -3, d_date))
order by yr
```